# pygame "Argument must be rect style object" error for collision

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

i'm currentely making a platform game and i'm blocked for the collisions... Can you help me ? I actually added some blocs to test the collisions, created a player under the class Perso. I really need to make work the collision to make after that portal and also have to elaborate a gravity to make the player jump. 
Here is my code:
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()

```
#pour créer une fenêtre
fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768))
pygame.display.set_caption("Portal Escape")

#pour créer un perso
class Perso(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    #self.image = pygame.Surface((100,100))
    self.image = pygame.image.load("perso.png").convert_alpha()
    self.position = pygame.Rect((3,660),(100,100))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

perso = Perso()

#pour creer un obstacle et éléments du jeu
def bloc():
bloc=pygame.Surface((200,200))
bloc_rect = bloc.get_rect()
bloc.fill((0, 0, 255))
fenetre.blit(bloc, (500,600))

red=pygame.Surface((200,500))
red_rect = red.get_rect()
red.fill((255, 0, 0))
fenetre.blit(red, (250,300))

portal=pygame.Surface((20,120)) #création d'un bloc portail
portal_rect = portal.get_rect()
portal.fill((0, 255, 0))
fenetre.blit(portal, (250,650))
blocx = [bloc,red,portal]

#Boucle du menu
continuer = 1
while continuer:
    accueil = pygame.image.load("menu.jpg").convert()
    fenetre.blit(accueil, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    continuer_jeu = 1
    continuer_accueil = 1
    choix = 1
#Boucle de l'accueil
while continuer_accueil:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30) #limite les frames de la boucle
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: #quitter le jeu
            continuer_accueil = 0
            continuer_jeu = 0
            continuer = 0
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN: #choix du menu
            if event.key == K_F1:
                choix = 1
                continuer_accueil = 0
#Boucle du choix
if choix != 0:
    fond = pygame.image.load("fond.jpg").convert()
    fenetre.blit(fond, (0,0))
    fenetre.blit(perso.image, perso.position)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(400, 30) #accelérer le deplacement quand la touche est enfoncée
    bloc()
    while continuer:
        for event in pygame.event.get():    #Attente des événements
            if event.type == QUIT:
                continuer = 0
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_DOWN and perso.position.y < 660:
                    fenetre.blit(perso.image, perso.position)
                    if perso.position.colliderect(blocx):
                        print("collide")
                    else:
                        perso.position.y += 3
                if event.key == K_UP: 
                    perso.position.y -= 3
                if event.key == K_RIGHT and perso.position.x < 920:
                    perso.position.x += 3
                if event.key == K_LEFT and perso.position.x > 3:
                    perso.position.x -= 3
        #on appelle les fonctions du jeu, le fond et les perso

        fenetre.blit(fond, (0,0))
        fenetre.blit(perso.image, perso.position)
        bloc()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

pygame.quit()

Comment: Your indentation is off, and there is a way too much code. Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
if perso.position.colliderect(blocx):
```

Should take the `Rect` of the surface:

```
if perso.position.colliderect(bloc.get_rect()):
```

Comment: Thanks the code worked but not dispaying "collide" in the console when touching the "bloc". Is it normal?

Comment: Ah yes, it is possible that you will need to call `bloc.get_rect()` at the time of collision. I have updated my answer accordingly. See if that fixes it.